# Any way to run a macro (in an open VS instance) from the command line?

Tags: visual-studio, macros

I typically run a script each night that updates my code from SVN, then builds it. The last few days I have a long debug run I'd like to start at night so it can go through the hour or two it takes to hit the error before I come in the next morning. The way I've done this so far is to VPN in later in the evening to start the run.

Is there any way I can have a script tell an active Visual Studio instance to execute a macro? Either that or launch a new instance that would run a macro once it's open. This way I could automate the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To **execute a macro or a command** in a new session, do:

```
devenv /Command CommandName
```

To **debug** an executable, do:

```
devenv /DebugExe ExecutableFile
```

To **run** a solution using default settings:

```
devenv /r Solution
```

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a329t4ed(VS.80).aspx